# If else statement in WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I use WooCommerce and I have one button on my index page, where I want to show different message for members and guests.

I have a lottery system and only registered users can use it. I want to put text as follows:

- On the members side: **Lottery**
- On the guest side: **Register**

**My code:**

```
if ( ! empty( $link ) && ! empty( $label ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="section-scroll btn btn-border-w btn-round">' . wp_kses_post( $label ) . '</a>';
}
```

**The code for my funtcion would be:**

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Lottery';
} else {
    echo 'Register';
}
```

Now how could I put this code to be variable and put it instead of `$label` variable. Is it possible with if else statement?

Comment: Not saying this is the right technique, but the ternary operator would be an option. `wp_kses_post( is_user_logged_in() ? 'Lottery' : 'Register' )`

Comment: That worked like a charm man! Can I add seperate links to them maybe?

Comment: Yep, you could use the same ternary style expression for the href, or you could put the whole anchor tag inside a single ternary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a separate `$label` and `$link` based on whether user is logged in or not:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $label = 'Lottery';
    $link = 'lotteryLink';
} else {
    $label = 'Register';
    $link = 'registerLink';
}
```

And after that use the existing code to display them:

```
if ( ! empty( $link ) && ! empty( $label ) ) {
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="section-scroll btn btn-border-w btn-round">' . wp_kses_post( $label ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: This helps mate, but how can I put a link? putting a link inside $link doesnt work.

Comment: You can simply use- if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $label = 'Lottery';
    $link = 'https://www.google.com';
} else {
    $label = 'Register';
    $link = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
}          they should work as intented when you use them on **href** as you're doing right now  (please add https:// infront of the links)